# does the order of the operands to comparison operators matter?

Tags: c#, coding-style

When checking if an object equals some value, is there some difference between:

```
myObject == someValue
```

or

```
someValue == myObject
```

In other words, does the order of the operands of the comparison operators matter? Is it a matter of coding style?

I have been using the former, but a project has been using the latter which I had never seen before.

For example

```
if (data != null)
    data.Write(writer);
```

or

```
if (null != data)
    data.Write(writer);
```

I have been using the former, while some member in the project has been using the latter.

Thanks.

Comment: The only difference is in readability. Most people find it more readable when hard coded values are on the right side of the comparison operator.

Comment: Matters, it does not, the order. `(null != data)` is colloquially known as a "Yoda condition". I whimsically used one in a fizz buzz five years ago interviewing for my current job, and they still give me crap about it. I'll normally do it only when the other operand is a long method call or some such, and putting the constant first decisively aids readability, But in that case maybe you should just be assigning it to a local instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any difference, or at least not one that the compiler wouldn't optimize to the same thing anyway.

What you're observing are often called [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).  (Because of the linguistic style of what the conditions sound like when spoken aloud, being similar to how Yoda speaks.)  And they're mostly a matter of personal preference.

People who advocate them are quick to point out advantages, for example:

```
if (something = true)
```

would produce a runtime bug, whereas:

```
if (true = something)
```

would produce a compiler error and be caught immediately.  Though I would counter-argue that unit tests should have found the error before it got far anyway.  And would equally argue that any confusion from other programmers on the team (even just the idle curiosity of you posting this question) is time lost on the project.  But I digress :)

Comment: also, `if( something = null)` should generate a warning.

Comment: @MikeNakis: May depend on the compiler and the language, but I agree that it should yes.

Comment: @MikeNakis It wouldn't generate any warning, it would produce a compiler error, as the expression won't resolve to a boolean in an `if` statement.  If the code were `something = true` *then* the code could actually compile, and if that were the code, it wouldn't generate a warning.

Comment: @Servy: Ah, good point.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: It's actually possible to get that line of code to compile if the type of `something` is a class that overloads the `true` and `false` operators or has an implicit conversion to `bool`.  But you may have deeper problems if you have a class doing that.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same in my opinion. If I say:

```
(1 != 2) = true

(2 != 1) = true
```

Both will result in the same answer. The only thing I can think of that would matter is if where you work there is a coding standard that requires one way or the other (I have never seen a coding standard like that).  I would stick with the same way the current project your working on is doing it.